# Using org-src-preserve-indentation only on specific code blocks (or buffers, or anything beyond the global context, really)

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I've been Googling and digging through the `org-babel` docs, but it's coming out with not a lot.

The thing is, one of things I'm working on is [using org-babel to tangle Makefile source](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-makefile.html). In it, the documentation states, and I understand why it does, that I need to evaluate `(setq org-src-preserve-indentation t)`, which I have, right now.

Thing is, I don't *want* to enable this value globally. I can understand that it makes sense for Python, Makefile, or other languages that are white-space sensitive, but I *really* don't want it enabled elsewhere. Plus, the end result of this is that the final org-file won't work for people who *don't* enable the value by default, so the resulting org-file is less portable anyway.

I'd prefer it if I could *just* enable `org-src-preserve-indentation` on a per code-block basis (it's extra typing, but I can live with that), but even a buffer-specific setting is acceptable. The thing is, I'm not sure how to do it.

I *suspect* that it *could* be done by taking advantage of how `#+HEADER` settings can eval Lisp code, but doesn't that mean that every time I tangle the file, or something, the setting is kept on every time? I'd rather not do that, that just makes the file unpredictable to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on feedback I received from [the Google+ org-mode group](https://plus.google.com/u/0/112928802151311265855/posts/dM41faC1qwW), as well as reading up on [buffer-local variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html), I finally ended up using `M-x add-file-local-variable RET org-src-preserve-indentation RET t` to finally add this code block at the bottom of my org-file:

```
# Local Variables:
# org-src-preserve-indentation: t
# End:
```

Once I refresh the local setup (i.e. press C-c on the header arguments), Emacs asks me if I want to use the buffer local variable, and then sets `org-src-preserve-indentation` to `t` for this buffer alone.

This appears to resolve the issue to my liking, so I'm going to mark this question closed.